# Why did Jack Vincennes set up the three men in the Nite Owl case?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

In *L.A. Confidential* when Ed Exley seeks Jack's help for investigating further into the Nite Owl's case, Jack refused. Then Exley said:

> Exley: **Do you make the Negroes for the Nite Owl killings?**
>
> Jack: What?
>
> Exley: It's a simple question...
>
> Jack: Why in the world do you wanna go digging any deeper...into the Nite Owl killings, lieutenant?...

This makes me think that Jack already knew of what he did, like he intentionally set them up. Is it true that he knowingly did this? If so why would he do that ? He was not one of Dudley's men or could it be that he was paid by someone like Sid ?

Comment: You've completely misunderstood this scene. I'm about an hour from the end of my work-day, and if no one else answers, I'll do a write up later. In a nutshell, "everybody knew' that Exley was looking for promotion. He killed at least one of the escapees and was given a medal of bravery for what he did. "Why in the world do YOU wanna go digging any deeper...LIEUTENANT?" Proving them innocent/framed would cost him his accolades and perhaps black-ball him from any further promotions (corrupt leadership). Plus Exley got promoted after going against the blue wall.

Comment: Ohh okay...I thought as he got suspected by Exley, he agreed to help him..